# DataDog: detecting mismatch of 2 custom metrics per host

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

How to display hosts in DataDog host map, where values of two custom metrics are not equal?

Saying I have metrics `custom.A` and `custom.B`, both are integer (DataDog represents them as floats but this doesn't change much). And I need my dashboard host map widget to detect hosts where `custom.A != custom.B`

The easiest way seems to check `abs(custom.A - custom.B)`. The following syntax is not accepted by DataDog widgets however:

```
"requests": {
    "fill": {
        "q": "max:abs(custom.A{*} - custom.B{*}) by {host}"
    }
}
```

Neither the stock graph constructor allows to build a map based on two metrics.

Any known solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.
I contacted DataDog support. Formulas are not supported in Host Map widgets in their current version of the product. They recommend to use another widget type instead, like Top List.